# How can I obtain the value of <input> responsively with the Shopify?

Tags: shopify, google-tag-manager

I want to add google tag management to the product for better management. So I want to get the products that customers buy. But when I want to obtain the number of product, I don't know how to get it responsively. So every time the user changes the number, I can get it.
This is the code which provided by Shopify:

```
<div class="product-form__item product-form__item--quantity">
  <label for="Quantity-{{ section.id }}">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
  <input type="number" id="Quantity-{{ section.id }}" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="product-form__input" pattern="[0-9]*" data-quantity-input>
</div>
```

This is the data I want to get:

```
<button onclick="dataLayer.push{"event":"addTocart","currencyCode":"",'products': [{
  "id": "{{product.id}}",
  "name": "{{ product.title }}",
  "price": {{ product.price | divided_by: 100.00 | json }},
  "quantity": {{data-quantity-input}}}]}" 
  type="submit" 
  name="add"
  {% unless current_variant.available %} aria-disabled="true"{% endunless %}
  aria-label="{% unless current_variant.available %}{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}{% else %}{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}{% endunless %}"
  class="btn product-form__cart-submit{% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} btn--secondary-accent{% endif %}"
  data-add-to-cart>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "customer changes the number"?

Comment: For example, if you buy something on Amazon, you can buy one or two or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would need to use the following `onclick` attribute:

```
<button 
  onclick='dataLayer.push({"event":"addTocart","currencyCode":"","products": [{
    "id": "{{product.id}}",
    "name": "{{ product.title }}",
    "price": {{ product.price | divided_by: 100.00 | json }},
    "quantity": document.querySelector("[data-quantity-input]").value}]})'
  ...
  other element attirubtes
  ...
>Add</button>
```

Comment: I used the code you provided, but I can't get the quantity. In the Web element it shows ```onclick="dataLayer.push({"event":"addTocart","currencyCode":"","products": [{
                    "id": "3724666175550",
                    "name": "PACK 15 - PACK DÉMÉNAGEMENT 15m²",
                    "price": 15.0,
                    "quantity": document.querySelector("[data-quantity-input]").value}]})"```

Comment: I get the above elements, just like the other ones you can get the corresponding data, but the"quantity" can't be got. It shows the codes rather than the input.

Comment: Is there a live URL to check this directly?

Comment: "https://shop.cartonplein.org/collections/frontpage/products/pack-10-pack-demenagement-10m". The 'onclick' is added to the button 'AJOUTER AU PANIER'

Comment: It's working properly. I just checked that it sends the correct quantity data. See the screenshot: https://yadi.sk/i/xj7YxUKyMsEBjw